# Is it possible to reuse a value in a stack?

Tags: multithreading, stack, fifo

I hope this isn't a stupid question. I'm currently trying to understand threads as also their memory allocation. There I came across the concept of a stack. And I believe to have understood the (rather easy) concept of a FIFO but what I don't understand is the following:

If I have a thread and execute it, then the method uses the stack for all of it's data but if the stack is FIFO then you'd only be able to use every piece of data once because once accessed the data is then popped from the stack. But what if I have a method which uses f.e. a variable twice or three times? Does the (compiled) process know in advance, that it has to put the data three times in the stack because it get's used 3 times or how does this work?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: What language is this asking about?

Comment: I had one one side Java in mind but on the other hand also C and in my work I want to compare them to Google's Go as I learned Go is handling parallelization quite differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically each call to a function or method gets its own stack frame. It’s the stack frames that get pushed and popped, not individual variables. So a method call can access the same variable multiple times because that method invocation is using the same stack frame to reference it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This makes much more sense to me. 
Is this the same with threads or is the thread stack a "real"/"pure" FIFO stack?

Comment: @Bantion: Each thread has its own stack of stackframes. at least this holds in C, Java, and Lisp. "same with threads" doesn't make a lot of sense, there isn't a thread-free version.